# How can we dynamically set types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am working on a small library that handles global states (key: value pair) in React.

As the library does not know what `key` will be set so I would like to create a type dynamically set when they use the library.

My code is like this:

```
import * as React from "react"
import {
  RecoilRoot,
  atom,
  selector,
  useRecoilState,
  RecoilState,
  SetterOrUpdater
} from "recoil"
import { is, isNil, has } from "ramda"

// stores all state values
const atoms: Map<string, RecoilState<KeyDefault>> = new Map()

export const MyLibProvider: React.FC<LibProps> = ({
  children,
  defaults = {},
  override = true
}) => {
  const Path = ({ children }: { children: LibProps["children"] }) => {
    if (isNil(atoms)) {
      throw new Error("no state values")
    }

    for (const k in defaults) {
      if (isNil(atoms.get(k))) {
        atoms.set(
          k,
          atom<KeyDefault>({
            key: k,
            default: defaults[k as keyof KeyDefault]
          })
        )
      }
    }
    return <>{children}</>
  }
  return (
    <RecoilRoot {...{ override }}>
      <Path {...{ children }} />
    </RecoilRoot>
  )
}

const Injection: React.FC<InjectionProps> = ({ _atoms, Component }) => {
  const $: { [key: string]: KeyDefault } = {}
  const setters: { [key: string]: SetterOrUpdater<KeyDefault> } = {}
  const updated: Map<string, RecoilState<KeyDefault>> = new Map()

  for (const v of _atoms || []) {
 
     const res: KeyDefault = is(Object)(v)
       ? (v as KeyDefault)
       : { key: v, default: null }

     const key = res.key
     if (isNil(atoms.get(key))) {
       atoms.set(key, atom(res))
     }
    
    const [val, set] = useRecoilState(atoms.get(key))
    $[key] = val
    setters[key] = set
  }

  const get = (key: WhatTYPE) =>
    typeof updated.get(key) !== "undefined" ? updated.get(key) : $[key]

  const set = (val: any, key: WhatTYPE) => {
    updated.set(key, val)
    setters[key](val)
  }

  return <Component {...{ $, set, get}} />
}

export const inject =
   (
     atoms: WhatTYPE?,
     Component: React.ElementType<ComponentProps<InjectionProps["_atoms"]>>
   ) =>
   () =>
     <Injection {...{ _atoms: atoms, Component }} />
```

And it will be used like this (i.e. in Next.js):

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <Roid defaults={{ state_1: 1, state_2: "two", state_3: "HELLO WORLD" }}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Roid>
    );
}

export default MyApp;

const Home: NextPage = inject(
    // At this point, `set` and `get` arg keys can be restricted to one of these?
    ["state_1", "state_2", "state_3"], // these are keys of the state
    ({ $, set, fn, get }) => {

        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <main className={styles.main}>
                    <h1
                        className={styles.title}
                        onClick={() => set(($.state_1 || 0) + 1, "state_1")}
                    >
                        Welcome to {$.state_1}! // use $ to get global state
                    </h1>
                    <h1
                        className={styles.title}
                    >
                        Welcome to {get("state_1")}! // Or get(key) returns global state
                    </h1>
                </main>
            </div>
        );
    }
);

export default Home;
```

In my .d.ts file I tries to define types like:

```
type RoidProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode
  defaults: { [key: string]: any }
  override: boolean
}

type KeyDefault = {
  key: string
  default: any
}

type InjectionProps = {
  default: KeyDefault[] | string[] | undefined
  Component: React.ElementType<ComponentProps>
}

// tried this but `KeyDefault[number]["key"]` becomes `any`
// and `keyof RoidProps["defaults"]` just gives me `string`
type GetKeysOf<TType> = TType extends KeyDefault[]
  ? KeyDefault[number]["key"]
  : TType extends string[]
  ? keyof RoidProps["defaults"]
  : never

type ComponentProps<T> = {
  $: any
  set: (val: any, key: GetKeysOf<T>) => void // type of key here should be keys of T
  // same below: type of key here should be keys of T
  get: (key: GetKeysOf<T>) => KeyDefault | RecoilState<KeyDefault> | undefined
}
```

Does anyone know how to set types dynamically and determined when the function is called?

Or is it even possible to do so?

Comment: Have you tried using a generics type for `atoms`?

Comment: @juliomalves You mean this `const atoms: Map<string, RecoilState<KeyDefault>> = new Map()`? Otherwise I don't think so... Could you give me some examples please?